# How to write jest test case for private function using jest

Tags: node.js, ts-jest

need to be write test case for below function in jest. I am new for jest coverage i check multiple document can you please help for write test case for forEach

```
      public mapResultsToDbResponses(results: any[]): IDbResponse[] {
        if (results) {
            const dbResponses: IDbResponse[] = [];
            results.forEach((result) => {
                dbResponses.push({
                    Items: result.Items,
                    Count: result.Count,
                    ScannedCount: result.ScannedCount,
                });
            });

            return dbResponses;
        }
    }
```

Comment: By definition you cannot test private methods ;), but try this: https://dev.to/danywalls/testing-private-methods-in-typescript-3np5

Comment: return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1); suppose i need to be write test case for this without considering this is private then how can i write.

Comment: I guess testing your function (and change It from private to protected) is better, because if somebody will change your method you miss this change...